# How to make eclipse not auto-indent a block of code

Tags: eclipse, indentation, auto-indent

I like Eclipse's auto-indent function, but sometimes I've got some indentation I don't want it to correct, like

```
audioBuffer1[j] = (short) (VOLUME_REDUCER * ( inputBuffer[i] 
                  + ALPHA *   inputBuffer[i - echo1a] 
                  + ALPHA *   inputBuffer[i + echo1a]
                  - ALPHA *   inputBuffer[i - echo1b] 
                  - ALPHA *   inputBuffer[i + echo1b] 
                           ));
```

which gets corrected to something horrible. Is there a way of making the auto-indent function skip over some bits of code, using an `@annotation` or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put // at the end of the lines you don't want it to wrap.

```
audioBuffer1[j] = (short) (VOLUME_REDUCER * ( inputBuffer[i] // 
                  + ALPHA *   inputBuffer[i - echo1a] //
                  + ALPHA *   inputBuffer[i + echo1a] //
                  - ALPHA *   inputBuffer[i - echo1b] //
                  - ALPHA *   inputBuffer[i + echo1b] //
                           ));
```

Answer (score 1):

For disabling auto-indent, see [bug 193688](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=193688) and [bug 319532](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=319532) (not before 3.7M2).
You will be able to set the preference to the Typing page to enable/disable smart indent on New Line. If disabled, it still indents to previous line.

---

Note: For format in general (since Eclipse3.6 JDT)

```
 class X {
   // disable-formatter
   void foo1() {}
   void foo2() {}
   // enable-formatter
   void bar1() {}
   // enable-formatter
   void bar2() {}
 }
```

The [bug 27079](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=27079) ("Tags for disabling/enabling code formatter") and its [attached patch](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=160659) are addressing that particular feature (which is not exactly what you want here).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an annotation to control formatting behavior, but I find it helpful to turn off Edit -> Smart Insert Mode prior to inserting a block of code that you don't want to be messed with.